# link connections/sessions over multiple servers through linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, linked-server, bandwidth

We were facing some bandwidth issue's and are trying to track down the root cause. I am no dba, but under the circumstances need to pick up the role :).

We are using a SQL 2014 and sql 2008 R2 server which are physically located on different sites (+- 5km apart) connected by a dedicated line.

it was this dedicated line that got saturated and the only thing we know it was the 2008 server asking a lot of data from the 2014 server.

I already combined the data I got from sp_who2 with below query to try and figure out what could be causing the workload.

SELECT *

FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS ec
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.most_recent_sql_handle) AS st

ORDER BY num_writes DESC

The problem is that we believe the query was triggered on 2008 server and that the query uses a linked server to get data from 2014 server.
Is there a way to track which query used a linked server (I know for example the user that this server uses) and link that to a session/connection on the 2014 server?

Been googling about this, but (maybe due to my limited sql server knowledge) haven't found anything.

thanks a million for any input!!

Comment: If you have the sql_text from your query, can you search through that for the name of the linked server?

Comment: @MJH, and whould there be a way to check what workload this is causing on the linked server? I know what is running on 2008 server and what is using the 2014 server, But don't really see which session/connection is generated on the 2014 server and creating workload. Maybe ask the question differently, how can I check which query is creating a lot of traffic, is this DiskIO from sp_who2 or number of reads from sys.dm_exec_connections or something else. If I check this on sql 2014 and get the query text I might be able to see where it is used on 2008.